# How do I email a javascript app to someone who doesn't have javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find something that can run my javascript project so that I can send it as a finished project?

I've tried googling for results, which wasn't helpful.
I also  found a few youtube videos. They didn't have much of what I wanted.

I have a friend who doesn't have javascript and I want to send him over my finished project.  Either as a file or an application, but I'd like it to be sent over so he can see it without the use of javascript and seeing the code.

Comment: Javascript is actually the best language for this purpose! Could you tell us a little more about your application? Is it a command line app?

Answer (score 5):

If they have a browser they have JavaScript. Package up your code as an HTML file that loads the JavaScript.

If this is a Node application then you may need to look at packaging it up differently. Installing Node isn't difficult, and it's available for [pretty much anything that can compute](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

For a more ambitious packaging you can use something like [Electron](https://electronjs.org) to make a distributable application. This is a larger investment of time, but it's the easiest for the user to use.